# AWS S3 multipart upload with Amplify failed with Error code 2 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, multipart

This is my first time with AWS S3, I am trying to implement AWS S3 multipart upload with amplify but I am getting this error again and again and it never finishes the upload.

Here is the progress block

```
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadExpression()
    expression.progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
        
        let completed = String(format: "%.2f", (progress.fractionCompleted * 100))
        print("Progress: \(completed)")
        GCD.async(.Main) {
            self.lblProgress.text = "Progress: \(completed)%"
        }
    }
```

Here is the completion block which never gets Error

```
var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityMultiPartUploadCompletionHandlerBlock
    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }else {
                print("Task status: \(task.status)")
            }
        })
    }
```

**Edit**
But if I change

```
let tuConf = AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration()
    tuConf.isAccelerateModeEnabled = true
```

this code from true to false it uploads small files successfully, which I am thinking is not getting divided into parts

Here is the screenshot of the error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although it explicitly talking about downloads, some are mentioning uploads as well in this thread - https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/420
Seems related to permissions on the bucket. Did you make sure it is configured correctly? Look specifically at the IAM policy part

Comment: Please check the updated question I've made an edit

Comment: Hmmm I see. Weird indeed. Did you try support?

Comment: No I haven't, I thought I should give stackoverflow a try as 90% of the time I've found the solution here